Possible to copy PCR/PTS/DTS data between TS files?
I've 2 h264/aac stream TS files (say a.ts and b.ts) that have same duration and packet numbers. However PCR/PTS/DTS data of their audio/video stream packets are different. How do I copy PCR/PTS/DTS data from a.ts to b.ts using ffmpeg or other tools without actually overwriting the audio and video frames data? Ideally want to do this without re-encoding.

This is a pretty specialized request. You may not find an existing tool that does what you want to do. Here is I would do:
Read the PMT to find the PID for the PCR.
If you find a PCR packet in the source adjust the time and copy the packet to your target.
The PTS and DTS are in the PES header. So you have to some parsing of the TS packets.
So if you encounter a PES header containing PTS/DTS in the source adjust the time and then copy the packet.
This task is not too difficult but will require some parsing and re-generating of TS packets.

Thanks for your response. How do I copy/overwrite packets between TS files? And, could I PM you to dicuss this in more detail?

I'd probably use something like this: https://github.com/Unit-X/mpegts/tree/master/mpegts
First read the Transport Stream packets - adjust the timestamps and then write them to another file.
